# Angular 4 parent component event listener won't triggered by child emitted event

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to pass an output from a child to its parent,
not sure why it's just won't work,

Child:

decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})

@Output() notify: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
onClick(){
  this.notify.emit('msg from child component');
}
```

imports:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
```

template:

```
<button (click)="onClick()"> search </button>
```

Parent:

```
onNotifyClicked(message: string): void {
  this.showMsg = message;
}
```

template:

```
<child (notify)="onNotifyClicked($event)"> </child>
```

I get to the state in which notify is being emitted (this.notify.emit('msg from search component');
runs, no error was thrown for the emit)
but I never get into the parent handler onNotifyClicked(),

Comment: How do you know that? Have you put a console.log in the parent handler?

Comment: @echonax I used breakpoints at first and didn't get into the handler, after your comment I added a console.log and nothing as well

Comment: Can you include your imports? Where do you import `@Output`?

Comment: @echonax yes thanks, just updated with the imports

Comment: Can you add child components selector ? (the @Component part) are they matching?

Comment: I've created a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a17ptm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts everything seems to be working.

Comment: Is child's button placed in `form` tag?

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy nop just divs

Comment: @echonax thanks I think I'll try to restart my mac or something, I found a plunker example with the same use case and it works perfectly, I don't have a reasonable explanation for this :/

Comment: @echonax all works, I guess I had to restart the dev env.. thanks a lot btw

Comment: @lironn hmm strange.. anyway glad you figured it out :-) you should delete the question if the case is no longer reproducable btw.

Comment: @echonax I tried to but stackoverflow wont let me :/

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable as,

```
@Output()
notify = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

Comment: appreciate your help, just tested it and still wont get into onNotifyClicked(), I'm using angular 4.2.4 and typescript 2.3.3, any idea?

Comment: @lironn create a plunker

Comment: someone did it for me --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a17ptm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work unless your parent is listening not in the child component directly (as in your post) but on one of its parents. Angular doesn't support event bubbling, so if your parent component has something like code sample below, it won't get the message:

```
<div (notify)="onNotifyClicked($event)">
   <child></child>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My steps were correct, I had to restart my dev env, whoever gets here - don't waste your time reading this use case.